# Need vLookup() for Adobe Acrobat Pro form

Tags: javascript, arrays, pdf

I am creating an evaluation tool that helps contractors (user) I work with show their customers the value of making certain energy-efficient upgrades.

It uses space types to determine the respective kWh and fuel use on a per-square-foot basis. The space types are in a dropdown the user will select.  A function will return the per-square-foot kWh and fuel based on their selection.

I built this in Microsoft Excel and now am trying to convert this to a standalone PDF. I need to recreate the same functionality as the VLOOKUP function in Microsoft Excel.

Everything I've looked at so far can't be done due to program design, was designed for implementation on an HTML webpage, or explains how to use the VLOOKUP function in either Excel/Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I did find a solution, but it was based on a class, and deconstructing the class might be the answer, but I've got until Thursday morning to demo the product.  It's Excel unless I can get this lookup feature working.

I have created several arrays to hold the space types, kWh, and the various fuel types.

Comment: what is a "vLookup" when it's at home?

Comment: Sorry, it is the same functionality in the Excel VLOOKUP() function.

I need to send a text value from a dropdown and return a. numerical value.

Comment: Sorry - I updated the post to be more informative.

Comment: Wasn't planning on using the web.